# jQuery Galleria is not working in any version of IE when loaded via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, galleria

I'm trying to load content into my page asynchronously, but jQuery Galleria won't initialize in any version of IE.

Having experienced this type of problem before, I'm pretty sure it relates to when elements become visible to the DOM.  I've tried using live(), setting a timeout, registering a custom event, but still no luck.

I appreciate any help you might be able to provide.

The problem is visible [here](http://made.cmfbeta.com/#!/fcprojects/diamond-tile-bed/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you made sure, that your jquery-code is inside

```
$('document').ready(function(){  ...  });
```

Furthermore, have you tried [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)?